# Move UITextView to bottom of ViewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

I created the textView and Button(reply) programmatically and I want to move it down to the bottom of my ViewController. It's now being placed under the label(Joshyjosh) and it shouldn't do that. Is there something I need to add to my code or change so it can move to the bottom?

[image]

```
import UIKit
    class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
var commentView: UITextView?
var footerView: UIView?
var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
let FOOTERHEIGHT : CGFloat = 50;
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if self.footerView != nil {
        return self.footerView!.bounds.height
    }
    return FOOTERHEIGHT
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: FOOTERHEIGHT))
    footerView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 243.0/255, green: 243.0/255, blue: 243.0/255, alpha: 1)
    commentView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: tableView.bounds.width - 80 , height: 40))
    commentView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    commentView?.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)
    commentView?.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    commentView?.scrollsToTop = true

    footerView?.addSubview(commentView!)
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: tableView.bounds.width - 65, y: 10, width: 60 , height: 30))
    button.setTitle("Reply", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 155.0/255, green: 189.0/255, blue: 113.0/255, alpha: 1)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.addTarget(self, action: "reply", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    footerView?.addSubview(button)
    commentView?.delegate = self
    return footerView
}

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {


    if (contentHeight == 0) {
        contentHeight = commentView!.contentSize.height
    }

    if(commentView!.contentSize.height != contentHeight && commentView!.contentSize.height > footerView!.bounds.height) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
            let myview = self.footerView
            print(self.commentView!.contentSize.height)
            print(self.commentView?.font!.lineHeight)
            let newHeight : CGFloat = self.commentView!.font!.lineHeight
            let myFrame = CGRect(x: myview!.frame.minX, y: myview!.frame.minY - newHeight , width: myview!.bounds.width, height: newHeight + myview!.bounds.height)
            myview?.frame = myFrame

            let mycommview = self.commentView
            let newCommHeight : CGFloat = self.commentView!.contentSize.height
            let myCommFrame = CGRect(x: mycommview!.frame.minX, y: mycommview!.frame.minY, width: mycommview!.bounds.width, height: newCommHeight)
            mycommview?.frame = myCommFrame

            self.commentView = mycommview
            self.footerView  = myview

            for item in self.footerView!.subviews {
                if(item.isKindOfClass(UIButton.self)){
                    let button = item as! UIButton
                    let newY = self.footerView!.bounds.height / 2 - button.bounds.height / 2
                    let buttonFrame = CGRect(x: button.frame.minX, y: newY , width: button.bounds.width, height : button.bounds.height)
                    button.frame = buttonFrame

                }
            }
        })

        print(self.footerView?.frame)
        print(self.commentView?.frame)
        contentHeight = commentView!.contentSize.height
    }


}
```

Comment: just make change in position of 'y' during framing of button & textView. As you are supplying 0 & 5. \n for moving at bottom just get screen height from [[UIScreen MainScreen]bound].size.height . Now subtract your textView height from screen height. Add resultant to Y posting during framing.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a beginner at this and I'm having trouble understanding what you said. Just don't know where to make the changes in my code. Is there any chance you could write out what you said in code format?